# Vb.net process close event

Tags: vb.net, process, shutdown

I'm asking a question which my mind goes blank on how it'll be coded... I'm trying to make a simple program that detects if a game closes, and when it does, it shuts down the computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the process, you can set [EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) to true, and the process will raise the [Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event.

As for shutting down the system - this is potentially more difficult.  You can P/Invoke [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx), but it requires specific permissions (`SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME`) or it will fail.

Comment: As I said, i'm a nub at processes (because i never thought of using them) however imma do some more research, thanks BTW